# Export data to google cloud storage from BigQuery select statement without temp table

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

Is there any way I can export the data to google cloud storage from select statement (BigQuery) without creating a table.

I have a requirement to pull data based on select statement (BigQuery) every day and put the file in google cloud storage.

I know we can do export from BigQuery following ways.

1. Command Line -- In this option I need to create a temporary table. I couldnt see any example or syntax without temp table.

bq query --destination_table=mydataset.happyhalloween "SELECT name,count FROM mydataset.babynames WHERE gender = 'M' ORDER BY count DESC LIMIT 6"
bq extract 'bigquery-public-data:samples.shakespeare' gs://example-bucket/shakespeare.csv

2. WebConsole  -- This option is out since need to schedule
3. API -- With API also I couldn't see from SQL Query. I see the examples with entire table.

Let me know is there any way to export the data to google cloud storage from Bigquery select statement without creating a temporary table.

Thanks,

Comment: why you think temp table is a problem for you?

Comment: I don't have write access to BigQuery, have only select permission and full permissions for bucket. So looking for the options to put the file directly into Storage instead of temp table.

Answer (score 3):

Query results are [always saved to either a temporary or permanent table](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/querying-data#queries).

When you specify a destination table, that is a permanent table, but if you don't BigQuery creates a short-lived temporary table to store the results. If you look at the **Query history** section, you can see the names of these temporary tables.

[image: query history]

I successfully was able to run an export job to Cloud Storage when specifying a temporary table as the source.

```
bq extract my-project:_63cfa3...c5d1ef7 gs://my-bucket/my_table.csv
```

Regarding using the API, you can see the destination table if you get the job after you insert it.

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/get

In my example, the response for getting the job ID associated with the query job shows

```
{
 "kind": "bigquery#job",
 "id": "my-project:bquijob_ca7e64e_15cf54562fb",
 "jobReference": {
  "projectId": "my-project",
  "jobId": "bquijob_ca7e64e_15cf54562fb"
 },
 "configuration": {
  "query": {
   "query": "SELECT \"ABC\"",
   "destinationTable": {
    "projectId": "my-project",
    "datasetId": "_63cfa399614a54153cc386c27d6c0c6fdb249f9e",
    "tableId": "anondca79e1ad06d03be556f3fc3fdbaaf2b9c5d1ef7"
   },
   "createDisposition": "CREATE_IF_NEEDED",
   "writeDisposition": "WRITE_TRUNCATE",
   "useLegacySql": false
  }
 },
 "status": {
  "state": "DONE"
 },
...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use EXPORT DATA OPTIONS command provided by BigQuery SQL

Query :

```
EXPORT DATA OPTIONS(uri="gs://example-bucket/shakespeare.csv",format='csv') AS SELECT name,count FROM mydataset.babynames WHERE gender = 'M' ORDER BY count DESC LIMIT 6
```

So using 'bq' command line utility it would be something like this

```
bq query --format=prettyjson --use_legacy_sql=false 'EXPORT DATA OPTIONS(uri="gs://example-bucket/shakespeare.csv",format='csv') AS SELECT name,count FROM mydataset.babynames WHERE gender = 'M' ORDER BY count DESC LIMIT 6'
```